# Android MVP: Should the presenter be notified about everything?

Tags: java, android, mvp

I am currently in the process of creating my first app using MVP architecture. Multiple times already I have come across the situation where the view will notify the presenter about some click events and the presenter will simply call a method on the view to do something in response. 
Look at this example:

```
interface ProfileView {

    /**
     * Displays the avatar photo stored at the given Uri path.
     * @param uriPath the Uri path which is pointing to the photos location
     */
    void displayAvatarPhoto(@Nullable String uriPath);

    /**
     * Sets and displays the user´s name.
     * @param name the user´s name to be displayed
     */
    void displayName(@NonNull String name);

    /**
     * Sets and displays the user´s email.
     * @param email the user´s email to be displayed
     */
    void displayEmail(@NonNull String email);

    /**
     * Sets and displays the user´s birthday date.
     * @param birthday the user´s birthday date
     */
    void displayBirthday(@NonNull String birthday);

    /**
     * Sets and displays the time when the user wants to be notified.
     * @param time the time when the user wants to be notified
     */
    void displayNotificationTime(@NonNull String time);

    void showSelectAvatarPhotoDialog();
    void showEnterNameDialog();
    void showEnterEmailDialog();
    void showEnterBirthdayDialog();
    void showSetNotificationTimeDialog();
}

interface ProfilePresenter {

    /* Lifecycle methods. */
    void onCreate();
    void onDestroy();

    /* Called when the user clicks on the corresponding views. */
    void onChangeAvatarPhoto();
    void onChangeNameClicked();
    void onChangeEmailClicked();
    void onChangeBirthdayClicked();
    void onChangeNotificationTimeClicked();

    /**
     * Called when the user wants to delete his current avatar photo.
     */
    void onDeleteAvatarPhotoClicked();

    /**
     * Called when the user has selected/made a new photo for his avatar profile.
     * @param uriPath the Uri path where the photo is stored, not null or empty
     */
    void onAvatarPhotoMade(@Nullable String uriPath);

    /**
     * Called when the user has entered a name for his avatar profile.
     * @param name the new name the user has entered, not null or empty
     */
    void onNameEntered(@NonNull String name);

    /**
     * Called when the user has entered an email for his avatar profile.
     * @param email the new email the user has entered, not null or empty
     */
    void onEmailEntered(@NonNull String email);

    /**
     * Called when the user has entered a birthday date for his avatar profile.
     * @param year the year the user was born
     * @param month the month the user was born
     * @param day the day the user was born
     */
    void onBirthdayEntered(int year, int month, int day);

    /**
     * Called when the user has toggled the notifications option.
     * @param notificationsEnabled whether or not notifications should be enabled
     */
    void onNotificationsToggled(boolean notificationsEnabled);

    /**
     * Called when the user has entered a time when he wants to be notified.
     * @param hour 0 - 23
     * @param minute
     */
    void onNotificationTimeEntered(int hour, int minute);
}
```

In the Fragment acting as the view I set the following listeners which will notify the presenter that the user has clicked something:

```
rowItemName.setOnClickListener(v -> mvpPresenter.onChangeNameClicked());
rowItemEmail.setOnClickListener(v -> mvpPresenter.onChangeEmailClicked());
rowItemBirthday.setOnClickListener(v -> mvpPresenter.onChangeBirthdayClicked());
rowItemNotificationTime.setOnClickListener(v -> mvpPresenter.onChangeNotificationTimeClicked());
```

The Presenter will then simply call a method of the view to tell it what to do:

```
@Override
    public void onChangeAvatarPhoto() {
        mvpView.showSelectAvatarPhotoDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeNameClicked() {
        mvpView.showEnterNameDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeEmailClicked() {
        mvpView.showEnterEmailDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeBirthdayClicked() {
        mvpView.showEnterBirthdayDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangeNotificationTimeClicked() {
        mvpView.showSetNotificationTimeDialog();
    }
```

My question is: Is this the right way to do this (if there is one) or is it better in such cases to let the view directly show a dialog in this example without the "unnecessary" call to the presenter?

Tanks a lot :)

Comment: I am running into the same questions a lot, but there is a lot of literature on the web pointing in all directions. So I guess there is not really an answer. If you truely wanna religiously follow MVP then you should do what you do. If you are a reasonable individual and your click events, just have UI consequences, then just skip the presenter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tended towards violating the MVP rules here (if there are real rules like you said), because I saw no gain I could get from this added layer of abstraction. Your answer confirmed my thought, so thanks a lot :)

Comment: EDITED: wrong thread

Comment: @Elias if you put that code in a preseneter, you'll be able to cover it with tests. Also there might be little business logic, e.g. sending analytics events